# How can I read Database Tables with Attributes

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, class, attributes

I want to read database tables with Attributes.
I have Table in database and I have class same fields name.
I want to transfer to my class which matched values in database using attributes.

For Example :

```
[ReadDBAttributes]
public class News{
   public string Title;
   public string Content;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What language are you using? What database? What attributes are you interested in?

Comment: If this is C#, then just use Linq to SQL or EF, that's exactly how they work.

Comment: I Use C# and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MySQL you'll need a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS News 
   (Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Title VARCHAR(20), Content Text);
```

Then you'll insert your data using escaped values where noted.

```
INSERT INTO News (Title, Content) VALUES ('[ESCAPED TITLE]', '[ESCAPED CONTENT]')
```

You can then read these back out in any number of ways (this assumes MySQL).

```
-- get most recent news
SELECT Title, Content FROM News ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1

-- get a specific item by id
SELECT Title, Content FROM News WHERE Id = [ID YOU WANT]
```